# The value for the useBean class attribute ... is invalid

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, properties

I want to use a Java file `SaveProp` which is written in a package `user`. The class file has been placed in `WEBINF/classes`. Below are the two lines which cause the issue.

```
jsp:useBean id="user" class="user.SaveProp" scope="session"

jsp:setProperty name="user" property="*"
```

It throws:

```
The value for the useBean class attribute user.SaveProp is invalid
```

I'm using Tomcat 6.0.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should put the file under WEBINF/classes/user

Comment: which file goes in that folder?  the .java, .class, .war?

Answer (score 44):

3 things

1. Make sure the class file is under WEBINF/classes/user
2. Make sure there is a public default constructor without arguments
3. You can also use type= instead of class= if the bean already exists in the scope

Answer (score 15):

Make sure that the default no-arg constructor is there and is public.