# JSP Page Won't Work: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp and The value for the useBean class attribute is invalid

Tags: java, jsp, exception, tomcat, javabeans

I am having an issue running a jsp file which uses a java class. The jsp file is called temp.jsp. I have put my jsp file in the ROOT folder on a tomcat server
The class is found in ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/com/java/tempBean.class

**Here is the all the code from my temp.jsp file:**

```
<jsp:useBean id="report" class="com.java.tempBean" scope="page">
</jsp:useBean>
```

**Here is all the code from my tempBean.class file (the class is empty - im just trying to produce no errors at the moment!)**

```
package com.java;


public class tempBean
{

    public tempBean()
    {
    }
}
```

When I try to open the jsp page I get the following errors (between refreshes I get either the first or second error)

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /temp.jsp (line: 1, column: 1) The value for the useBean class attribute com.java.tempBean is invalid.


    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:41)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:148)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1229)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$UseBean.accept(Node.java:1182)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:475)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3485)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:249)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:372)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:352)
        org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:339)
        org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:601)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:344)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

OR

```
exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.temp_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:168)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:356)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.temp_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:162)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:356)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Any help is really appreciated :) thanks!

Comment: Try using `type` attribute instead of `class` attribute. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545177/the-value-for-the-usebean-class-attribute-is-invalid/1764211#1764211

Comment: changed the attribute to type: get this exception now:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the jsp file: /temp.jsp
com.java.TempBean cannot be resolved to a type
1: <jsp:useBean id="report" type="com.java.TempBean" scope="page">
2: </jsp:useBean>

Answer (score 1):

Apprantely the class file was not being picked up when I manually added it to the tomcat server (i probably would have to restart the server for it to pick it up but I couldn't do that as it is not my server!) , I exported my code as a WAR file from Eclipse and put it in the webapps folder (the server does automatically pick up these) and now it works.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

See question [The value for the useBean class attribute ... is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545177/the-value-for-the-usebean-class-attribute-is-invalid)

Probably not the reason for the error, but Java class names should always be capitalized:

```
package com.java;

public class TempBean
{
    public TempBean()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) i renamed my class anyway but it didn't do anything. I looked at the answers to that question earlier but it did not fix my issue unfortunately :(