# JSTL giving Error when trying to access bean

Tags: java, tomcat

I have been at this for over a week. I am getting an error when I try to access my bean. My error reads:

```
The value for the useBean class attribute beans.Bean is invalid.
                 org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:41)
```

Here is the the code:

```
package beans;

public class Bean {

private String message = "This is from the bean";

public Bean(){

}

public String getMessage(){

    return message;
}
```

}

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>

<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<%@ page import = "beans.Bean" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"          "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<!--Location of Css file-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/format.css" type="text/css"  />

<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="intro">
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>1</th>  
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
</tr>       
<tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<jsp:useBean id="message" class="beans.Bean" scope="session" />

<p>From the bean: <c:out value="${message.getMessage()}" /></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I am using Tomcat 8 and my JDK is 8 as well. I have added the jstl.jar file to my class path, the tomcat lib folder and to the WEB-INF lib folder. I also deleted Tomcat 7 because I read there might be conflicts with two Tomcat versions downloaded.

Please, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The value for the useBean class attribute ... is invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545177/the-value-for-the-usebean-class-attribute-is-invalid)

Comment: No it not a duplicate. I already looked at those posts.

Comment: in that case, please add more information indicating the steps you tried. E.g. where is your Bean.class file? Bizarrely, the question and answers I linked to all say `WEBINF` when they should say `WEB-INF`

Comment: I added my bean class file to the post. A class file is by defaulted java class files are added to the java resources->src->somefile.java. As for what I tried I is listed at the bottom. However I summed it up on what I have and am using. This are all issues that I worked out as I went along and thought it would result in less reading for any future posters if I sum it up clearly for them.

Comment: How are you compiling/building your code? Simply putting your `.java` file into the webapp in tomcat isn't enough, it needs to be compiled to a `.class` file, and that `.class` file needs to be in `WEB-INF/classes/beans` as (almost) described in the answers I linked to. Your IDE or build process may be doing this for you, but it sounds like you're missing that step.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to my own probelm:

There was a conflict with my JSTL.jar files. I had two different ones in my J2EE library folder and this whole time I kept looking into the JDK folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use message.message instead of message.getMessage()

Comment: that's not the issue - please see the error message at the start of the question

Comment: I have tried that before and it did not work and I added the <%@ page import = "beans.Bean" %>  just to see if it made a difference which it did not. Even worse I sent a buddy the code and it worked for him. I have no idea at this point. I have java 8 SDK selected, using Tomcat 8 put all the Jar files in there correct places. I have not altered the web.xml file but that really should not matter in this case.

Comment: @jocdrew21 Please see my last comment on the question - if this worked for your buddy, it's because he is correctly building the `.class` file from your java source, and getting it into `WEB-INF/classes/beans`. The jar files are not your issue and nor is the the web.xml.

Comment: Not correctly building the java source file correctly? I created the Beans.java file, and it is located in the Java Resources->src folder, and the JSP is in the WEB-INF folder. The jars files have been added to the correct locations, I have the program and hit the run button in Eclipse. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @jocdrew21 if you reply to a comment from someone other than the author of the answer you're commenting on, you need to @ mention them or they won't be notified. Also, this comment thread is not really the right place to be discussing anything not directly related to this answer, but my bad there for starting it.

Comment: @CupawnTae this is directly related to the question if it is causing the issue. Is this not what this forum is for? Google an error and prehaps find a person whom already had an issue before in hopes of solving it rather then spending 1 1/2 weeks on a issue like me.

Comment: I meant the comment thread under ngueno's answer is not the correct place. You'll probably see a warning here now saying to avoid extended discussions in comments. ngueno gets notified every time we comment here, and we're not discussing this particular answer so this isn't the right place