# IntelliJ IDEA - The value for the useBean class attribute is invalid

Tags: java, jsp

I use tomcat 8.0.26 & jdk 1.7.

In my WEB-INF > classes > beans, it's a Student.java & Student.class.

```
  package bean;

  import java.io.*;
  public class Student implements Serializable{
    String name;
    String address;
    String phone;
    String email;

    public Student() {
        name = "";
        address = "";
        phone = "";
        email = "";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone() {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

  }
```

In my reg.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <% request.setCharacterEncoding("utf8"); %>
  <jsp:useBean id="bean" class="bean.Student" scope="page" />
  <jsp:setProperty name="bean" property="*" />
  <jsp:getProperty name="bean" property="name"/>
  <jsp:getProperty name="bean" property="address" />
  <jsp:getProperty name="bean" property="phone"/>
  <jsp:getProperty name="bean" property="email" />

  </body>
  </html>
```

But the file shows:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /web/reg.jsp (line: 15, column: 0) The value for the useBean class attribute bean.Student is invalid.

Is there something wrong?

My steps are:

1. Create jsp files

   Create package and java file in 'src'

   copy the package into the Project's WEB-INF.

I have read the answer: [The value for the useBean class attribute ... is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545177/the-value-for-the-usebean-class-attribute-is-invalid?rq=1) , but it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, I read these answer but can't solve my problem

Comment: it should, if you actually did it. You're not compiling the Java source I guess, and thus at runtime the class file doesn't exist, thus it can't be found. This has nothing to do with your IDE btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my WEB-INF > classes > beans, it's a Student.java & Student.class.

Is the folder name under classes **beans** or **bean**?
If it is **beans** it should be renamed as **bean**