# java -- runing java server pages @ Apache tomcat server

Tags: tomcat

> HTTP Status 500 - /main.jsp (line: 10, column: 9) The value for the useBean class attribute TestBean is invalid.

type Exception report

> message /main.jsp (line: 10, column: 9) The value for the useBean class attribute TestBean is invalid.

```
The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /main.jsp (line: 10, column: 9) The value for the useBean class attribute TestBean is invalid.
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:443)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:149)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1305)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$UseBean.accept(Node.java:1196)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2392)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2444)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2450)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:474)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2392)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3591)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:251)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:660)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.82 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.82

It is to be noted that any other java server pages is running fine. The problem comes only when a java class is referenced from the java server pages.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have missed one or more of the following things:

1. Ensure that the class files are under `WEB-INF/classes/<packagename>`
2. Ensure that there is a `public` and a default constructor, i.e., without any arguments

It would be good to check on these points before you proceed any further on resolving your issues that you have reported here.

You can refer to the following questions for better understanding of your problem as well:

[Issue-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024507/jasperexception-the-value-for-the-usebean-class-attribute-is-invalid)

[Issue-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545177/the-value-for-the-usebean-class-attribute-is-invalid)

Hope this helps!